# Loop function and array: javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

I'm looking to declare a function that can generate a series of ordered pairs of values within an array, such as can be plotted on a graph. I have two variables:

```
var xAxis = 1;
var yFunction = 4*(xAxis^xAxis) + 12(xAxis) + 20;
```

so, basically this would use *Flot* for *JQuery* to plot a quadratic equation on a graph, but I want to be able to use, say, a while loop to increment the `xAxis` variable by one on every iteration, and then compute the `yFunction` value for `xAxis` on that iteration. I'm not sure how to keep `yFunction` pegged to the present value of `xAxis`.

Also, the function has to generate each value of `xAxis` and yFunction for every iteration and then store these values into an array of the format:

```
var graphArray = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 6], [4, 8]];
```

And from there, I can plot the graph.

If anyone has any idea how I would go about doing this, I'd be grateful. I've looked around forms and can see no obvious solution to my very specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your starting point is to define the `yFunction` as a function:

```
var yFunction = function(x) {
    return 4 * Math.pow(x, x) + 12 * x + 20;
}
// assuming that by x^x you meant X to the power of X.
```

Then your loop may be something like:

```
var graphArray = [];

for(var x = 1; x <= 4; x++) {
    graphArray.push([x, yFunction(x)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function y(x) { //handle y as function as learned in school
    return 4 * (Math.pow(x,x)) + 12 * x + 20;
}

var objValueTable = {}, //object to store data into
    targetValue = 10; //value to iterate to
for(var x = 1; x != targetValue + 1; x++) {
    objValueTable[x] = y(x); //store value of y at point x in object
}
```

should work well. See [example via jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/4EzNy/1/).
targetValue is the number of iterations the function should do.

Comment: can I just ask why the for loop condition has '!=targetValue + 1' as a condition?

Comment: The second statement (x != targetValue + 1) is for ending the loop if it returns false. So, if x reaches 10, the loop would stop without executing y(10) because x != 10 is false. That's why I'm adding the startingValue to the targetValue. In most cases you would start by zero (for(var i = 0;...)). But i != targetValue + 0 does not make sense.